# How to disable/hide icon from a form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, vcl

How do I create a second form with a close button,but without an icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set form's BorderStyle to bsDialog and use this code on form create,

```
SetWindowLong(Handle,gwl_style,GetWindowLong(handle,gwl_style) or WS_THICKFRAME);
ClientHeight := Height;
Refresh;
```

I think it's an ugly hack but you may find it ok.

Comment: I will accept it,because it's a great alternative,but the close button is not looking the same as if the window's borderstly was bsSizeable.I'm skinning my form,that's the problem.But thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Set the form's BorderStyle to bsDialog.

Comment: The border then is too small.

Comment: You could also remove biMinimize and biMaximize from BorderIcons

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do it in other way, than experimenting with BorderStyle property, since this is done by VCL internally.